# Crystal Report - Images not showing up

Tags: c#, image, crystal-reports, report

I know there's a lot of topics about it but I tried everything people told and nothing worked.
I'm creating a report in my C# library project (there's no AppConfig or WebConfig) from database and I have a column in my table that is VarBinary.

I tried using an sub report linked to my database to show the image and it didn't work. I also tried to use an image from a folder, using the URL in a Picture object and the image was still not there. I don't know if that matter but I have a windows service that starts the process inside this library. All other datas from database shows up in the report. The idea here is to return to the user an report from any company and I want to show the company logo at the header.

Ps: I can't share any image here because of my company policies, sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the image format is not supported by Crystal.

For a list of supported image formats, see:
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1964141

That document indicates the following formats are: JPG, BMP, PNG, or TIFF (depending on version).